# Javascript AI make stupid moves - minmax function in Tic-tac-toe

Tags: javascript, minmax

I am struggling for the second day what is wrong with my minmax function in Tic tac toe game. Even spending two days on code I can not found the problem with the mechanics
[Codepen](https://codepen.io/kozuba/pen/XWPqQqg)

The computer is making the moves, but they are not the best moves, in fact I can win every time in three moves

The code consist of the function bestMove, which is going through all the fields of the tic-tac-toe board and minmax function which, depending of the maximizing or minimazing player is looking for the highest or lowest value

```
    function bestMove() {
        let bestScore = -Infinity;
        let move;

        for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            if (board[i] == '') {
                board[i] = 'O';
                // eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign, prefer-const
                let score = minimax(board, 0, false);
                board[i] = '';
                if (score > bestScore) {
                    bestScore = score;
                    move = { i };
                }
            }
        }
        board[move.i] = 'O';

        activePlayer = player1;
    }

    // Minimax

    function minimax(board, depth, isMaximizing) {
       
        let result = checkWin();
        if (result !== false) {
            return scores[result];
        }

        if (isMaximizing) {
            let bestScore = -Infinity;
            for (let i = 0; i < 9; i += 1) {
                // Is the spot available?
                if (board[i] == '') {
                    board[i] = 'O';
                    
                    let score = minimax(board, depth + 1, false);
                    board[i] = '';
                    bestScore = Math.max(score, bestScore);
                }
            }
            return bestScore;
            // eslint-disable-next-line no-else-return
        }
        if (!isMaximizing) {
            let bestScore = Infinity;
            for (let i = 0; i < 9; i += 1) {
                // Is the spot available?
                if (board[i] === '') {
                    board[i] = 'X';
                    // eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign, prefer-const
                    let score = minimax(board, depth + 1, true);
                    board[i] = '';
                    bestScore = Math.min(score, bestScore);
                }
            }
            return bestScore;
        }
    }
    // Game vs hard computer

    if (index === '2') {
        if (e.target.innerText === '') {
            board[e.path['0'].id] = activePlayer.mark;
            desc.innerText = `Computer move`;
            const indexes = Array.from(Array(board.length).keys());
            const availableIndexes = indexes.filter((indexe) => board[indexe] === '');
            if (availableIndexes.length > 0) {
                bestMove();
            }
            desc.innerText = `${player1.name} move`;
            checkWin();
            createBoard();
        }
    }
```

Which part of my minmax function could go wrong, that I do not receive the best moves from Computer

Comment: Please, ask about specific problem

Comment: Do you not have it backwards? O is trying to minimize and X is trying to maximize? Try just switching the values for an X win and an O win.

Comment: In my case 'O' is computer, which should be the maximizing player, as I good understand

Comment: @kozuba If O is trying to maximize, why is X winning +10 instead of -10? `@` me so I get a notification please

Comment: @ChrisHamilton - many many thanks! Now I cannot beat the computer! Really appreciate!

Answer (score 0):

t seems that the issue might be with the way you are determining the best move in the bestMove() function. you are only keeping track of the highest score and its corresponding move, but you are not considering the possibility that there might be multiple moves with the same highest score

you can modify your if statement in the for loop in the bestMove() function to include an additional condition that checks if the current score is equal to the best score, and if so, you can randomly choose between the two moves. heres an example of how you can modify the if statement:

---- code -----
if (score > bestScore || (score === bestScore && Math.random() < 0.5)) {     bestScore = score;     move = { i }; }
---- code -------

Comment: Thank you for support, unfortunately that does not help